# How big, or small, are humans when compared to everything from the subatomic to the universal level on a scale of 1-100.?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, mathematical-physics

First time poster, so go easy on me! I have this question in 3 forms. Feel free to answer one, none, or all three. If unsure about the data, or potential missing data, go with what makes the most sense to you

On a scale of 1-100 where does a 6ft human find itself placed?

First, 
For the minimum use a small atom (radius ~0.1 nanometer) 
The max (largest sun) = UY Scuti ~(1,708 ± 192 R☉)

Second, 
Min = Electron (radius 2.82 x 10-15 meters) 
Max (largest quasar) = S5 0014+81 (radius 118.35 billion kilometers)

Third, 
Min = Quark (radius 0.43⋅10−16 cm) and 
Max = Hercules-Corona Borealis Great Wall (18 to 23 billion light-years (5.5 to 7 billion parsecs) in length)

Fourth,
Do you think there is a better mathematical approach to acquiring a clearer perspective of our size in the cosmos?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this website: http://htwins.net

Answer (score 0):

So one way you could solve this question is by using transformations on the number line. First you can slide by the minimum and then scale by the maximum to fit your 1-100. Your max, min and 'human' should be in meters.

You first find out by how much you need to slide your number line such that $0$ is the min point you choose. You do $$b=-min$$ where $b$ is the displacement factor

Then you do a stretch of the number line to fit your scale of 1-100. To find the scale factor $k$ you do $max*k=100$ so 
$$k=100/max$$

Then to find where a human or any size lies on this new stretched and displaced number line you do:

$$(x-b)*k=y $$
Where $x$ is the original size and $y$ is the new size $(0-100)$

Using this you should be able to plug in any value for the min and max and see where on the $0-100$ it lies